# Can Doxygen/Graphviz generate a PNG larger than 32766px?

Tags: doxygen, graphviz

I am trying to generate a `doxygen` package with one enormous class hierarchy. (It's for QuickFIX, FWIW). No matter what I do, it seems to be capping the height of the image at 32766:

`$ file html/inherit__graph__23.png
html/inherit__graph__23.png: PNG image data, 307 x 32766, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced`

It's not clipping; it's scaling. The result is that at only 307px wide, the class boxes are scaled so small that the text inside them is not readable, and the HTML map doesn't work, either.

Neither the `dot` nor the `doxygen` documentation mention this limit, though it seems clear something is doing it, and I can't find any directives to override it. (And yes, I realize an image that big has its own problems in browsers, but I'll deal with that later.) That number seems suspicious due to its proximity to 2^15, and I believe PNG uses a 32-bit size field, so something bigger should be possible.

Anyone know where that limit is coming from and how to bypass it?

Edited to add: doxygen version = 1.6.1, graphviz = 2.26.0. Maybe too old?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm screwed. The 32K limit is imposed by cairo, which is what graphviz uses underneath the hood to render PNG.

Reference: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.cairo/21068

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're correct. It's too old; you're not going to be able to exceed that limit unless you manage to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I upgraded doxygen to 1.8.7 and graphviz to 2.38.0. That image is now scaled at 32767px height. So, one more pixel. There's definitely some limit kicking in here that needs to be blasted through.